# DotNet HighCharts in MVC3, bind data from dictionary

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, linq, highcharts, dotnethighcharts

I'm building web report and trying to use DotNet HighCharts to create nice looking report. 
I have a dictionary:

```
ReportDict<Line, List<Shift>>
```

where:

Line is a simple class with few Strings and int

Shift is simple class with few String and int

each Line have several Shifts

I'm trying to create column chart which for each Line will display sum of Shift Output (One of the int in Shift class)

This is what I have now:

```
Highcharts chartOverall = new Highcharts("chartOverall")
            .InitChart(new Chart { Type = ChartTypes.Column })
            .SetTitle(new Title { Text = "Output" })
            .SetSeries(ReportDict.Select(s => new Series { Name = s.Key.Line.Name, Data = new Data(new object[] {s.Value.Select(d=> d.Output)})}).ToArray()
            );
```

Edit: 
When I change SetSeries to the below one and select only one Shift for each line it displays how I want it.

```
.SetSeries(ReportDict.Select(s => new Series {
Name = s.Key.Line.Name, Data = new Data(new object[] {
s.Value.Select(d=> d.Output).ToArray()})}).ToArray()
```

When I select more then one Shift for the Line, IE asks me to stop the script.

How to make it work?

Many thanks

Comment: Do you use any wrappers ? I advice to familair with http://www.highcharts.com/download

Comment: yes I use DotNet.HighCharts wraper

Comment: So I advivce to contact with authors of wrapper